# Is there a native Ubuntu version of Mario Forever?

Tags: wine, games

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I also have wine.

I was hoping that there was some version of Mario Forever that does not require wine. Is there any such version, and if yes, does anyone have a link or command to install it?

Comment: Being an old-time Mario fan and having never heard of Mario Forever, your question caught my attention. However, a bit of googling revealed that there are a lot of games that you could mean: 1. [Here](http://fantendo.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Mario_Forever_Series) are several *Mario Forever* games for Nintendo DS. 2. [Here](http://www.softendo.com/free_downloadable_games) are several fanmade *Mario Forever* games. 3. [Here](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Super_Mario_Forever) is a *Super Mario Forever* game that is a hack of the original Super Mario Bros. Could you clarify which one you mean?

Comment: Mario Forever i want it

Answer (score 1):

No. According to the Community of Mario Forever, it is not possible to compile Mario Forever into Linux since CF2.5 doesn't allow to do that (that's what they said).
BUT
There are some Mario Forever Fan Games that have Native Linux Support from Other Game Engines.
Ex. Mario Forever Multiverse 2 has Linux Support
Although there is not Original Mario Forever Remade on Linux yet. But maybe some day...